# Vegan para R 3.3.3

Tags: r

Estoy intentado instalar Vegan y bioconductor en R 3.3.3 pero el programa me muestra que esos paquetes no están disponibles para la versión que tengo

> ```
> install.packages("vegan")
> Installing package into ‘C:R/win-library/3.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning message:
> package ‘vegan’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)
> ```

Alguién sabe si estoy haciendo algo mal o si la nueva versión está limitada para ciertos packages?

Comment: install.packages("vegan",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")   intenta se está forma.

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de instalar `vegan` en windows con R 3.3.3 e instaló sin problemas. Lo que pudo haber pasado en tu caso puede haber sido lo siguiente:

### 1. Que lo intentaste muy cerca a la actualización de R 3.2 a 3.3

R tiene sus versiones como mayor.menor.parche. Actualizaciones mayores (de `2.x.x` a `3.x.x` por ejemplo) no pasan muy frequentemente. Actualizaciones menores (de `3.2` a `3.3`) pasan mas a menudo. En ambos casos hay que actualizar todos los paquetes, porque requiren ser compiladas nuevamente contra la nueva version de R.

En windows, por defecto bajas una version compilada desde CRAN. Y estas compilaciones se demoran un poquito despues de la actualización de R. No mucho, así que hay que llegar justo en el momento que aún no se ha compilado una nueva version, pero es posible que se de.

En este caso puedes esperar, o compilarlo tu mismo en tu computador. Los pasos son:

1. Instalar [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)
2. Bajar el paquete como codigo fuente (*source*), en este caso:

   `install.packages("vegan", type = "source")`

### 2. Que el paquete no funciona con la versión actual de R

A veces se rompen cosas en un paquete con actualizaciones mayores y menores de R. En estos casos el proceso de compilación automatica, que corre en CRAN y mantiene las versiones binarios de los paquetes actualizados va generar un error, y va resultar en que el paquete parezca no estar disponible para windows.

En este caso, el paso arriba te dará un error tambien. Si eso pasa siempre ayuda escribirle al autor or encargado (*package maintainer*) para alertarlo al error. Hay una alerta automatica de CRAN, pero que un humano esté esperando acción muchas veces ayuda a acelerar el proceso.

Estas dos son las razones más comunes. [Hay una lista mas larga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa?answertab=votes#tab-top) con un listado completo de razones por las cuales puede aparecer este error. Pero ya vas más allá del caso puntual de `vegan`.

Espero que mientras tanto esto ya se te habia resuelto y esta respuesta quede solo para dar un poco de contexto.